# jQuery: media queries for carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Wondering if there's a solution for this, can't seem to figure it out, I'm looking for the jQuery equivalent of media queries to change the function of a carousel I've got setup. 
The code is quite simple:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(function () {
        $(".events-slider").jCarouselLite({
            btnNext: ".next",
            btnPrev: ".prev",
            scroll: 3,
            speed: 800
        });
    });
});
```

But I have some css media queries set up, whereby at `900px` the `.event-slider` reduces in size, thus now only showing 1 slide as apposed to 3, I therefore want to change the jQuery function to reflect this, i.e. when the browser window reduces below `900px` the `scroll: 3,` attribute changes to `scroll: 1,` if this is at all possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery .width() function on $(window) to find the width of the browser's viewport, similar to the solution to this thread:

[jQuery: How to detect window width on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720294/jquery-how-to-detect-window-width-on-the-fly)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var window = $(window);

function checkWindowWidth() {
    var windowsize = window.width();
    if (windowsize > 900) {
        $(function () {
            $(".events-slider").jCarouselLite({
                btnNext: ".next",
                btnPrev: ".prev",
                scroll: 3,
                speed: 800
            });
        });
    } else {
        $(function () {
            $(".events-slider").jCarouselLite({
                btnNext: ".next",
                btnPrev: ".prev",
                scroll: 1,
                speed: 800
            });
        });
    }
}
checkWindowWidth();
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```