# Jquery if do something else don't do it

Tags: jquery, if-statement, media-queries

I have this code and I wan't to say, if the window is not smaller than 1024, don't do any of these things. How do I write this?

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {    
        $('#right > .info').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#middle').remove();
    }
    else {
    }
});
```

Comment: prepend to your handler: `if ($(window).width() > 1024) return;` But then, what is supposed to do the `else` statement??? In fact, your question doesn't really make sense. Am I missing something?

Comment: Else, don't remove class and else don't remove #middle?

Comment: Hope this makes it clearer: http://jsfiddle.net/m/gsp/

Comment: Cannot log to your jsfiddle... And what could be the opposite of .remove()???  You should detach element, not remove it. The opposite of removeClass() is... addClass()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing what you are trying to do, is something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
        if ($(window).width() <= 1024){ 
             $('#right > .info').removeClass('hidden');
             $('#middle').hide();
        } else {
            $('#middle').show();
            $('#right > .info').addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
```

The difference being, that you do not `remove()` (permanently remove it from the DOM), but rather `hide()` and `show()` it.

You might want to make in into a function and call it not only on resize, but also on page load.

This question might give you some inspiration: [jQuery: How to detect window width on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720294/jquery-how-to-detect-window-width-on-the-fly)