# How to stop youtube video autoplay only in mobile version?

Tags: css, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am using youtube videos on a website [here](http://www.atlanticveinclinics.com/)

I have set a video to autoplay on home page. And In responsive mobile version (below resolution 767px) I hide the video using css display none. But video is still playing in the backend.

I did all this because I want to change the position of video in mobile version , so I hide the right sidebar video in mobile version and display the left side video.

Now I want to stop the video in mobile version when it is hide. But the video is still playing even when it is hidden using css. I know css can not stop iframe autoplay.

**Is there any method which can relate the autoplay of youtube video depending upon the resolutions of the screen.** So that we can play and stop the video as per the resolutions of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use **Javascript** to load the **youtube video embed url** as per the screen resolution **dynamically**, instead of using a static video url

This **[link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml)** may help to detect Screen Resolution.

If you feel the Screen Size is small , just remove youtube autoplay parameter from the url

EDIT: Check this **[url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720294/jquery-how-to-detect-window-width-on-the-fly)** for Dynamic screen size handling

Comment: In the link screen.availWidth is giving the available width of the screen, but I want to get the current screen width as like we reduce the size of our window from 1322 px to 767 px then it return the same result.

Comment: Then check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720294/jquery-how-to-detect-window-width-on-the-fly